# Calling AJAX function after another one

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have something I cannot understand how to do it in AJAX. I have a sidebar and a div "content"  in my page. The sidebar is made of button and onclick it call the classical function:

```
  function loadDoc(url) {
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
   }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
 }
```

It load the "url" of the button in the content. Well, at this point everything is ok. Now one of this url, say "TheUrl", is a document that contain title and so on, and a div "list" and in this list I would like to load an XML file. I have the function

```
function loadXML() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    myFunction(xhttp);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "file.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<ul>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ITEM");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    table += "<li>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ELEMENT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</li>"
    };
    table += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = table;
}
```

But I have no idea how to load the function loadXML() after loadDoc("TheUrl") so that the Xml data appears in the div list that was create in the div content... I am clear ?? :D

I would like something like that in my sidebar:

```
<ul>
<li><button type="button" onclick=loadDoc("OtherUrl.html")>OtherUrl</button></li>
<li><button type="button" onclick=loadDoc("TheUrl.html").done(loadXML())>TheUrl</button></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: you can call one function in another function.

Comment: you can call `loadXML` in the `loadDoc` `onreadystatechanged` event. It's simple.

Comment: if you use `jquery ajax` you will have access to `promises`. then you can use `done` or `fail` callbacks to do the `post processing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the **loadXML** function in the **onreadystaechange** event of the first AJAX call like so:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
          // call the other function
         loadXML();

       }
```